# File.Exists() incorrectly returns false when path is too long

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently working on a program that traverses through various directories to ensure that specific files are present by using `File.Exists()`.

The application has been claiming that certain files do not exist when they actually do, and I recently discovered that this error was due to the path being too long.

I realize there are questions on SO that address `File.Exists()` returning incorrect values, but none seem to solve this particular issue.

Renaming the directories and files to shorten the path is not really an option, so I'm not sure what to do at this point. Is there a work-around that would solve this problem?

The code in use is nothing special (I've cut out some irrelevant code), but I will include it below just in case it helps.

```
    private void checkFile(string path)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
            Console.WriteLine("   *  File: " + path + " does not exist.");
    }
```

Comment: It's not returning `false` incorrectly. It's obeying the documentation: "The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or if the caller does not have permission to read the file."

Comment: Are the files located in a special folder?

Comment: Why are you checking in the first place? The file system is volatile, so you're just setting up a race condition. You still have to be prepared to catch an exception when the file is deleted between making the .Exists check and using the file, and in the meantime the call to .Exists() causes an extra (and very expensive) additional trip out to disk. Better to put your energy and code into that exception handler.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn If done correctly it can avoid exceptions in the standard code path.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, yes, according to the documentation the method's result is fine, but in the sense of practical functionality it is incorrect. I suppose my wording could have been better though.

Comment: @Keplah: it doesn't go by "sense of practical functionality". It goes by documentation alone.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Nowhere in my question did I state that I was using the file in the application. I realize that it seems silly when I say that, but the sole purpose of this program is to verify files are present.

Comment: @banging I realize that... Hence the first part of my comment.

Comment: I must ask this.  Is this a file your program creates?

Comment: @Ramhound No, they are created outside of the program.

Comment: What file system are you using that allows you to have long filenames/paths?

Comment: @JonSenchyna Like you, I'm using W7. I would think long paths would be disallowed in any context, but when saving a txt file for example, the path length is not taken into account, so you can exceed the maximum length. The same is true for saving word documents, pdfs, and just about anything I have come across so far.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution that works using DirectoryInfo and FileInfo.  It's not necessarilly efficient, or pretty, but it does work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is ugly and inefficient, but it DOES get around the MAX_PATH limitation:

```
const int MAX_PATH = 260;

private static void checkPath(string path)
{
    if (path.Length >= MAX_PATH)
    {
        checkFile_LongPath(path);
    }
    else if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   *  File: " + path + " does not exist.");
    }
}
```

And here is the checkFile_LongPath function:

```
private static void checkFile_LongPath(string path)
{
    string[] subpaths = path.Split('\\');
    StringBuilder sbNewPath = new StringBuilder(subpaths[0]);
    // Build longest subpath that is less than MAX_PATH characters
    for (int i = 1; i < subpaths.Length; i++)
    {
        if (sbNewPath.Length + subpaths[i].Length >= MAX_PATH)
        {
            subpaths = subpaths.Skip(i).ToArray();
            break;
        }
        sbNewPath.Append("\\" + subpaths[i]);
    }
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sbNewPath.ToString());
    bool foundMatch = dir.Exists;
    if (foundMatch)
    {
        // Make sure that all of the subdirectories in our path exist.
        // Skip the last entry in subpaths, since it is our filename.
        // If we try to specify the path in dir.GetDirectories(), 
        // We get a max path length error.
        int i = 0;
        while(i < subpaths.Length - 1 && foundMatch)
        {
            foundMatch = false;
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                if (subDir.Name == subpaths[i])
                {
                    // Move on to the next subDirectory
                    dir = subDir;
                    foundMatch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (foundMatch)
        {
            foundMatch = false;
            // Now that we've gone through all of the subpaths, see if our file exists.
            // Once again, If we try to specify the path in dir.GetFiles(), 
            // we get a max path length error.
            foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                if (fi.Name == subpaths[subpaths.Length - 1])
                {
                    foundMatch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // If we didn't find a match, write to the console.
    if (!foundMatch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   *  File: " + path + " does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks for sticking with the question!

Comment: Do note that is always assumes you're looking for a file, not a directory.

Answer (score 13):

From [MSDN - Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247#maxpath):

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following
>   paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is
>   defined as 260 characters.
>
> ...
>
> The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to
>   permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of
>   32,767 characters. This type of path is composed of components
>   separated by backslashes, each up to the value returned in the
>   lpMaximumComponentLength parameter of the GetVolumeInformation
>   function (this value is commonly 255 characters). **To specify an
>   extended-length path, use the `"\\?\"` prefix. For example, `"\\?\D:\very
>   long path"`.**
>
> ...
>
> Because **you cannot use the `"\\?\"` prefix with a relative path**,
>   relative paths are always limited to a total of MAX_PATH characters.

(Emphasis added)

If all your paths are full paths, you could update your code to use the extended-length path specifier as follows:

```
const longPathSpecifier = @"\\?";

private void checkFile(string path)
{
    // Add the long-path specifier if it's missing
    string longPath = (path.StartsWith(longPathSpecifier) ? path : longPathSpecifier  + path);

    if (!File.Exists(longPath))
    {
        // Print the original path
         Console.WriteLine("   *  File: " + path + " does not exist.");
    }
}
```

**Update:**

> For file I/O, the "\?\" prefix to a path string tells the Windows
>   APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows
>   it straight to the file system. For example, **if the file system
>   supports large paths and file names**, you can exceed the MAX_PATH
>   limits that are otherwise enforced by the Windows APIs.

At least on my system (using Windows 7), long file names are not supported, so I can't verify if the above solution will work for you.

**Update:** I found a solution that does work, but it is fairly ugly.  Here's what I did in pseudo-code:

1. Split the path into an array of directories
2. Get the longest portion of your path that is less than 260 characters (MAX_PATH).
3. Create a [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) for that portion of your path ("dir" for future reference).
4. For the remaining directories in your path:
   a. Call `dir.GetDirectories()` and check if the next directory is contained in the results
   b. if so, set `dir` to that `DirectoryInfo` and keep digging
   c. if not, then the path doesn't exist
5. Once we've gone through all of the directories leading up to our file, call `dir.GetFiles()` and see if our file exists in the returned `FileInfo` objects.

Comment: Does `File.Exist` support `\?\\` paths? Most .net APIs don't.

Comment: I can test it out and get back to you.

Comment: It looks like both `File.Exists(path)` and new `FileInfo(path).Exists` do not work with "\\?\", at least for my file system (Windows 7).

Comment: @JonSenchyna Same here... It doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: What file system are you using and how are your long paths being created in the first place?

Comment: @JonSenchyna (From above :P) Like you, I'm using W7. I would think long paths would be disallowed in any context, but when saving a txt file for example, the path length is not taken into account, so you can exceed the maximum length. The same is true for saving word documents, pdfs, and just about anything I have come across so far.

Answer (score 6):

You need to P/Invoke Win32 APIs to get this to work properly:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint GetFileAttributes(string lpFileName);

    public static bool DirectoryExists(string path)
    {
        uint attributes = GetFileAttributes(path.StartsWith(@"\\?\") ? path : @"\\?\" + path);
        if (attributes != 0xFFFFFFFF)
        {
            return ((FileAttributes)attributes).HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool FileExists(string path)
    {
        uint attributes = GetFileAttributes(path.StartsWith(@"\\?\") ? path : @"\\?\" + path);
        if (attributes != 0xFFFFFFFF)
        {
            return !((FileAttributes)attributes).HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Never had the issue myself, someone on another SO post suggests opening a handle to the file, thus avoiding the whole 'exists' check in the first place. Not sure if this still has the 'long filename' issue:

It's the second answer here:

[Check if a file/directory exists: is there a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570930/check-if-a-file-directory-exists-is-there-a-better-way)

Not sure if that's useful :P

Comment: You sort of missed the entire problem the author had.  He is trying to verify something exists, and the method is returning false, he would still have to locate the file in order to get a handle to the file.

Comment: @Ramhound I think you're missing the point of this answer. You can attempt to open the file, and if the file doesn't exist it will throw an IOException that you can handle and filter (i.e "file not found" or "file in use")

Comment: Opening the file is the same thing as checking if it exists - if the file can't be opened you get an exception, the only difference is that it *might* avoid the long filename issue, like I said, don't know if it's useful

Comment: Opening the file using `File` or `FileInfo` has the same path-length limitation as checking if the file exists.

Comment: Thought that might be the case - like I said, might not be useful :D

Answer (score -3):

**Check**

1. Manifest permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2. Use file provider to create and access file

```
    <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="your_package.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_list" />
    </provider>
```

3. file_list content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
        <external-path
            name="external"
            path="." />
        <external-files-path
            name="external_files"
            path="." />
        <cache-path
            name="cache"
            path="." />
        <external-cache-path
            name="external_cache"
            path="." />
        <files-path
            name="files"
            path="." />
    </paths>
```

4. Keep your filename short