# How can I run a command with administrator rights with Visual Studio code terminal?

Tags: windows, npm, visual-studio-code

The new version 1.2.0 includes a terminal, but when I try to install any pack with [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), I get the *"npm ERR! code EPERM"* that I usually solve by right-clicking and running it as administrator. How can I do that in the Visual Studio Code terminal? Is there something like [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) for Linux?

[image: Visual Studio Code terminal]

Comment: Found the answer myself, just run visual studio code as administrator. Just right click on it.  Don't know why I didn't think of that earlier.

Comment: is there no other workaround to this? I've been running Visual Studio for years as admin but this just seems 'wrong' somehow. Also sometimes in VSCode I don't have to do this. Is it only when a package is being deleted or updated that you'd get this?

Comment: ` just run visual studio code as administrator. Just right click on it.' **it works only if you close all instances of VScode before**

Answer (score 236, accepted):

#### Option 1 - Easier & Persistent

Running Visual Studio Code as Administrator should do the trick.

If you're on Windows you can:

1. Right click the shortcut or application (EXE file)
2. Go to *Properties*
3. *Compatibility* tab
4. Check "Run this program as an administrator"

##### **There is a caveat to it though**

Make sure you have all other instances of Visual Studio Code closed and then try to run as Administrator. The [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) framework likes to stall processes when closing them, so it's best to check your [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)) and kill the remaining processes.

##### **Related changes in the codebase**

- https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/8915236-visual-code-w-terminal-integrated-and-super-admin
- *[Running a command with administrator rights? #7407](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7407)*

#### Option 2 - More like Sudo

If for some weird reason this is not running your commands as an Administrator, you can try the `runas` command. [Microsoft: runas command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.11).aspx)

##### Examples

- `runas /user:Administrator myCommand`
- `runas "/user:First Last" "my command"`

##### Notes

- Just don't forget to put double quotes around anything that has a space in it.
- Also it's quite possible that you have never set the password on the Administrator account, as it will ask you for the password when trying to run the command. You can always use an account without the username of Administrator if it has administrator access rights/permissions.

Comment: The default location for the executable is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe`

Comment: when I use runas "user:domain\adname" "npm install -g @angular/cli" I get an error "RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - npm install -g @angular/cli  the system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: If it's unable to find npm you may need to add your node install to the System `PATH` environment variable. You can also try to verify if it exists by doing something like `where.exe npm` or `npm -v` to display the version. Also if you're using powershell sometimes you have to add exe at the end so you would have something like:  `runas.exe /user:Administrator myCommand`

Comment: You will not be able to use mapped drives in your project or code with Option 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32715171/5060792

Comment: Like the answer mentions, you might find that you've never set your administrator password, if that's the case, leaving the password blank won't work (on Windows 10 at least), but you might also find that your own user account is also an administrator, so use your own user name instead of `Administrator` and you'll achieve the same result.

Comment: Also, the integrated terminal won't be reused if you use `runas`, instead, a new console window will open where the argument command will be executed. It will close itself afterwards, to keep it open, use `cmd /k {command}`.

Comment: Yes. Running as administrator worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: _Make sure you have all other instances of VS Code closed_ Ugh. 20 minutes wasted before landing here. Thank You.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It drives me crazy that electron apps still don't close properly on Windows like: Spotify, Slack, Discord, Todoist, VSCode; I think one of them does handle it properly, but it drives me nuts that they all never fully close : \

Answer (score 79):

**Step 1:** Restart Visual Studio Code as an administrator

(click the Windows key, search for "Visual Studio Code", right click, and you'll see the administrator option)

**Step 2:** In your Visual Studio Code PowerShell terminal run [`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812.aspx)

Comment: This works.  I don't know why everyone is still upvoting other answers when this is working.  Have I missed something, is there a drawback?

Comment: This even has the benefit that you don't have to confirm running VSC as an administrator on startup.

Comment: This is the correct answer!  Kudos to you, sir!

Comment: This worked for me. Option 1 in the the accepted is not working

Comment: Works, sadly it isn't persistent, unless I'm missing something. Will stick to Option 1 of the accepted answer.

Comment: Make sure all Visual Studio Code windows are closed. If any non-administrator windows are open, the new window won't have administrator privileges.

Comment: how exactly do you set this? doesnt work from the commandline terminal in vscode

Answer (score 6):

Running as administrator didn't help me (I also got errors with syscall: rename).

It turns out this error can also occur if ***files are locked*** by Windows.

This can occur if:

- You are actually running the project
- You have files open in both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code.

Running as administrator doesn't get around Windows file locking.

I created a new project in [Visual Studio 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2017) and then switched to Visual Studio Code to try to add more packages. After stopping the project from running and closing Visual Studio 2017 it was able to complete without error.

*Disclaimer:* I'm not exactly sure if this means running as administrator isn't necessary, but try to avoid it if possible to avoid the possibility of some rogue package doing stuff it isn't meant to.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what happened to me. Closing the other applications that uses the folder and then reinstalling via cmd in Admin.

Answer (score 5):

In my case even while running as admin I had to set the execution policy.

In the terminal type:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy  Unrestricted -Scope Process`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy  Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine` to affect all users and all sessions. see also `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` to see more

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways you can solve this problem,

> **For temporary** 
> You can follow these steps for it,
>
> 1. Search Vscode after in the windows.
> 2. Then right-click and run the VScode as an administrator.

But you can do this every time when you open the VScode.So I supposed it is not the best way to solve this problem.

> **Best way** 
> You can follow these steps for it,
>
> 1. Search Vscode after in the windows.
> 2. Then right-click and click the open file location.
> 3. Then you can click the VScode icon and go to the properties.
> 4. Next you want to go to the compatibility tab.
> 5. At the bottom of the tab, there are selection boxes, in there you can see run this program as an administrator selection box you want to
>    tick it.
> 6. Then you can apply those changes and save it.

You can refer to below page to do more things related to this run as administrator stuffs
https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11841-run-administrator.html

Comment: tried the best way but now my terminal isnt loading properly :/  niether bash nor powershell load. I cant type anything into them.

Comment: turned off run as admin in compatibility mode via right clicking the shortcut and accessing it via properties now it loads again but not sure about if I have admin rights

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I get.

I'm using Visual Studio Code and its Terminal to execute the 'npm' commands.

**Visual Studio Code (not as administrator)**
PS g:\labs\myproject> npm install bootstrap@3

Results in scandir and/or permission errors.

**Visual Studio Code (as Administrator)**
Run this command after I've run something like 'ng serve'

PS g:\labs\myproject> npm install bootstrap@3

Results in scandir and/or permission errors.

**Visual Studio Code (as Administrator - closing and opening the IDE)**
If I have already executed other commands that would impact node modules I decided to try closing Visual Studio Code first, opening it up as Administrator then running the command:

PS g:\labs\myproject> npm install bootstrap@3

Result I get then is: *+ bootstrap@3.3.7

added 115 packages and updated 1 package in 24.685s*

This is not a permanent solution since I don't want to continue closing down VS Code every time I want to execute an npm command, but it did resolve the issue to a point.

Comment: I also have the same issue with my new laptop. @Jacques, do you know why this happen?

Comment: @Ivan absolutely no idea. Although I haven't had this happen in a while, but I can't tell you what changed

Comment: According to the documentation -the integrated terminal shell is running with the permissions of VS Code. This may be true, but in my case (problems with NVM commands), and in using Bash as my default terminal, I had to *also* set the permissions for GitBash itself to always run as administrator. Easy to accomplish in Bash with a right click on exe location > properties > compatibility > run as administrator, not sure of a persistent way to do it in Powershell (or Windows Terminal).

Answer (score 3):

From MS: "With the introduction of process sandboxing (discussed in this blog post) running as administrator is currently unsupported when AppLocker is configured due to a limitation of the runtime sandbox"

The work around is to disable sandboxing but starting VS Code with the following arguments:

```
--no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox
```

1. Create a shortcut.
2. Edit shortcut properties
3. Set the Target field to
   `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox`
4. Right click on shortcut and Run as Admin.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that solved the issue for me:

Right-click on the Visual Studio Code EXE file → *Compatibility* → Check *"Run this program as administrator"*

Answer (score 1):

Creating a shortcut and setting *Run As Administrator* on the *Compatibility* tab doesn't just set the Visual Studio Code to run as administrator when opened from that shortcut. It sets the underlying executable to run as administrator no matter how it is opened, which means you lose the ability to run Visual Studio Code in normal non-elevated mode.

As a solution that is a non-starter for me.

Rather than enable administrator mode in the *Compatibility* tab I find it easier to just open the normal Visual Studio Code shortcut using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of `enter`, that also runs it elevated, but I can still run Visual Studio Code normally by just opening it using <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to run commands with Administrator rights from the command line to get the Linux `sudo` experience in Windows, with none of the issues mentioned in the other answers. Output of commands run with `sudo` appears below the command in the same Terminal window as the command as expected, no need to quote usernames, set passwords, etc.: `sudo` for Windows.

You can find the `sudo` script in the `psutils` script collection in the Github repository at: https://github.com/lukesampson/psutils

You can install `sudo` easily using [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/). At a command prompt, run:

```
scoop install sudo
```

To run a command with Administrator rights, simply run it with `sudo`:

```
sudo .\myscript.ps1
```

You will be shown a UAC dialog before the command is run.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, *or* from another cmd, type:

```
    powershell -Command "Start-Process code -Verb RunAs"
    powershell "start code -v runAs"
```

The second line is just a shorter version. An empty cmd will pop up, but you can close it.

Answer (score 0):

Open power-shell as administrator and run

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me on windows 11, as of 2024jan.
This is the most consistent behavious,which does not require you to do the

1. Right click in the folder, open in terminal (you can also open terminal as an adminsitrator if you like). Then run `python myscript.py` and it will work.

Enabling administrator mode in the compatibility tab of the app works in few scenarios but the one i suggested should work in all scenarios.