# ng serve blocked by group policy

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-code

In visual studio code powershell I'm getting "this program is blocked by group policy" when I run ng serve -o in terminal window.  Any ideas how to fix this

[image]

several people suggested running the app as an administrator.  I did that as you can see below, but I got the same error

[image]

Comment: ng is a tool for angular not for angularjs. please change your tag

Comment: Run the console as administrator

Comment: how do you run the console as admin.  I just press ctrl+`

Comment: I right clicked Visual Studio Code and ran as admin, but that didn't work

Comment: I tried the solutions below but they didnt work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700536/visual-studio-code-terminal-how-to-run-a-command-with-administrator-rights

Answer (score 1):

The terminal window should be open as Admin