# VSCode Running PowerShell script VS each command separately produces different results

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Starting to manage servers with PowerShell scripts...

I installed VSCODE + PowerShell extension in my laptop.

I set my WSMAN Trusted list to *

And ran the following script (below, for example with F5 key) that suppose to stop a service in the remote machine:

```bsh
$computers = "IP ADDRESS"
[string] $domainAdminUserName = "USERNAME"
[string] $domainAdminPlainPassword = "PASSWORD"
$securePassword = $domainAdminPlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $domainAdminUserName, $securePasswordEnter-PSSession -Computer $computers -Credential $credentials
    
$svcSQL = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Computer $computers -Credential $credentials -Filter "Name='MSSQLSERVER'"
$svcSQLAgent = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Computer $computers -Credential $credentials -Filter "Name='SQLSERVERAGENT'"
$svcOLAP = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Computer $computers -Credential $credentials -Filter "Name='MSSQLServerOLAPService'"
    
Invoke-Command -Computer $computers -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.name -eq $svcSQL} | Stop-Service -Force}
Invoke-Command -Computer $computers -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.name -eq $svcOLAP} | Stop-Service}
    
Exit-PSSession
```

The services weren't stop

Then, I went to the PowerShell Integrated Console and execute the following commands:

```bsh
PS> Enter-PSSession -Computer "IP ADDRESS" -Credential "DOMAIN ADMIN USER"
PS> PASSWORD: ******
PS [IP ADDRESS]> Get-Service -Name "MSSQLSERVER"
PS [IP ADDRESS]> PowerShell found the service
PS [IP ADDRESS]> Stop-Service -Name "MSSQLSERVER"
```

The service was stopped successfully

How can I fix the problem in order to run the script and get the expected result?

---

*Note:*

1. PC: My pc (WIN 10 is in one domain (Home)
2. VM: My remote lab machine (WIN 2016 is in another domain (Work)
3. PC: To get remote access to my lab I need to use VPN app
4. PC: My WSMan `Trusted List = *`
5. VM: WinRM is running in my remote lab (GPO: Windows Remote Management (WS-Management (Startup Mode = Automatic)
6. VM: port 5985 is open, 5986 not
7. PC & VM: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in client and server wasn't help

Comment: Remove `[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]`. These are meant to be used with parameters, not for simply declaring variables in the code. If parameters is what you want, put the first three lines inside a `Param(..)` block

Comment: @Theo. thanks for the comment. fixed the code block and its work without errors.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Well done!

Comment: @Theo - Now for the main issue - Do you have any clue how to solve this issue? Is there any configuration need to do with VSCODE to make it work as with the usual Windows PowerShell?

Comment: I guess the Powershell editor is more forgiving than VsCode. I don't think you should try to make any effort in VsCode accepting code that does not follow syntax rules. Just use `[Validate*]` on parameters, not in variable creation.

Comment: There can also be a difference in the PowerShell version that is used in vscode vs the ise, making code work in the one , but not in the other.

Comment: Does it stop the service locally instead?  Why don't you use invoke-command?  Interesting though; I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @Hiddai, have you tried the drop-down menu at the top of the terminal window in VSCode that allows you to 'Select Default Shell'?  Windows PowerShell should show as a choice if there is a path to it.

Comment: @js2010 after some tests. I found that waiting a few sec\mins after each of the following commands: Enter-PSSession, Get-Service and Stop-Service - really stops the requested service. Running the scripts as a whole (press F5 (run) Key) does not stop the service. Note: Add " | Out-Null" or "Wait-Process" to the command wasn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally problem solved: l add the domain name as a suffix in the DNS suffixes list in the Network adapter > IPv4 properties

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning but had a similar issue that was resolved when I added this:

```
PS>  Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

[Visual studio code terminal, how to run a command with administrator rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700536/visual-studio-code-terminal-how-to-run-a-command-with-administrator-rights)