# When compiling Gatsby, I get an error, and if I reset VS Code, the error disappears

Tags: gatsby

I'm new to Gatsby, I find that every time I need to compile, for some reason I had to cancel the current compilation, I always get an error:

```
Failed to remove .cache files. EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\madvikinggames\gatsby\gatsby-styled-components\gatsby-starter-styled-components\.cache\_this_is_virtual_fs_path_\$virtual'
```

And all I have to do is to kill that terminal, leave VS Code, re-enter VS Code, open a new terminal, and npm run start again

Some other times the error is related to copying some files

It seems to be some kind of permission I have to give VS Code, but I don't know what

Comment: No idea why you are getting voted down, I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the VS Code terminal doesn't have enough permissions to remove the `.cache` and the `/public` folder, something that you should have in the develop command along with other actions that you are not allowed to perform.

Try opening the VS Code with administrator rights:  [Visual studio code terminal, how to run a command with administrator rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700536/visual-studio-code-terminal-how-to-run-a-command-with-administrator-rights)

Comment: No Ferran, I tried it, and it's the same, it's weird