# How to fix a Group Policy error when running NPM Startup Scripts in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm-start

I wanted to make the first website on react js, but when I first start using "npm start", this error is displayed:

PS D:\HTML and CSS programming\el.journal.web> npm start

> el.journal.web@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.

I tried typing: el.journal.web@0.1.0 start, doesn't work, tried this: react-scripts start, all to no avail. I also tried to enter: "expo start", it doesn't work either.
I tried to look for a solution to the problem on the Internet, there is nothing or it does not suit me, please help me.

Comment: Try to remove package-lock.json and node_modules and then run npm install and npm start again from a cmd (or another terminal) as admin

Comment: Yes, it really works, if I run the command: npm start in the console as an administrator, then it will run and open the site. But if I try to execute the command: npm start in "visual studio code", the problem will remain.

Comment: Hope this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700536/visual-studio-code-terminal-how-to-run-a-command-with-administrator-rights