# Override the location of chache for Numba

Tags: python, caching, numba, librosa

Librosa isn't working since today (The last time I used it, two weeks ago, it worked fine) so I tried a few things and came to the troubleshooting of the librosa devs: https://librosa.org/doc/main/troubleshooting.html

It might be a permission issue.
They provide a fix but I don't understand how to do it.
Can anyone explain me what I have to do please?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try following these steps?

Comment: I don't know what a cache directory is and how to override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by starting VS Code as an admin. (Close all windows like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700536/how-can-i-run-a-command-with-administrator-rights-with-visual-studio-code-termin).)