# Could not find part of the path

Tags: c#, xml, iis, directory, xmldocument

Ok, before I say anything else, let me note that I know this has been asked multiple times on SO. However, I have scoured the internet and haven't been able to find a solution for my particular case.

I'm trying to take an XmlDocument object and save it to a network drive. It works perfectly when I try to save it to my local C drive, but when I try to save to a network drive, either testing locally or from an IIS7 web server, I get the error "Cannot find part of the path V:\Test\DocName.xml". Here is the code I am using to try and accomplish this:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(@"V:\Test", doc.DocumentElement.Name + ".xml"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    doc.Save(stream);
```

doc is, of course, an XmlDocument. I have double and triple checked that I have rights to the directory, and I know for a fact that it exists and is not hidden or anything. Any ideas?

Comment: And V is a mapped network drive on the server? And directory Test exists?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct

Comment: Yes, Test exists

Comment: I'd remote into your web server and make sure that it has the V drive mapped correctly.

Comment: What happens if you open Windows Explorer, click the address line, and paste: `V:\Test\\`? Does it open that directory?

Comment: It navigates to the directory -- yes, it opens that directory

Comment: Also, even if I take out Test and try to save to the root of V:\, the same thing happens

Comment: Maybe the backslash needs to be escaped?

Comment: No, that's what the @ is for

Comment: Can you do a writeline of the final path?

Comment: Yep, it's correct...even the error message says it correctly: V:\Test\DocName.xml

Comment: Another idea for a test (if you don't want these long shots tell me, I'll go away :) try a simple `File.WriteAllText(...)` to see if that does work. And perhaps also a different file name, in case the current one got locked by your previous tries somehow.

Comment: It's a different file name every time, I'm just using that on here as a placeholder. I'll try the WriteAllText thing though

Comment: Same result with File.WriteAllText

Comment: Are you running VS as Admin?

Comment: Have you tried the UNC path `\\server\share\path-to\filename.xml`. Drive mappings are per user. Does your app pool user have drive mapped?

Comment: Yes. Don't forget though, this continues to happen even after I deploy to IIS web server...

Comment: I have tried the UNC path, but not the app pool user mapping...how would I do that? It's running under ApplicationPoolIdentity right now and I have impersonation turned on on my site.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/257174/using-mapped-drives-with-iis Mapped drives are never supported by IIS. You have to use UNC paths, even if that requires you to learn how to configure access permissions, which would be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Drive mappings are per user. See more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32715171/939213).

This means that if Visual Studio is not running under the same account as your mappings, it won't find it.

Also IIS is presumably running under a different "user". So same there.

Answer (score 0):

From [Using Mapped Drives with IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/257174/using-mapped-drives-with-iis)

> Drive mappings are an extension to the net use command and are created on a per-user basis. That is, the entries for drive mappings exist under the Hkey_Current_User registry key for the user who maps to the network drive. Also, drive mappings are created with the credentials of the user who is currently logged on.

As .NET websites run in an AppPool and this is associated with an account, usually a service account, it will not recognise any drive mappings.

It is recommended in .NET applications to use UNC paths instead of drive mappings.