# In UWP, how do I locate a pdf file on clicking a button to check if a pdf file is present or not?

Tags: c#, uwp

My code is as follows:
I used the File.Exists(path) but this doesn't seem to work.
Would appreciate all help.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
private async void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String path = @"C:\Users\Karan\OneDrive\Desktop\2010.pdf";
    String t = Main(path);
    if (t=="1")
    {
        Test.Text = "1";
    }
    if (t=="0")
    {
        Test.Text = "0";
    }
}
public static string Main(String path)
{
    String t;
    if(File.Exists(path))
    {
        t = "1";
    }
    else
    {
        t = "0";
    }
    return t;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UWP Check If File Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119464/uwp-check-if-file-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I locate a pdf file on clicking a button to check if a pdf file is present or not?

UWP app is running in sandbox, but `File.Exists` is System.IO api. So it could not work for accessing file except `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`. If you do want to check if the file exist in the desktop, we suggest you add [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#example) capability and enable in the system file access setting. This capability works for APIs in the `Windows.Storage` namespace.

```
try
{
    var file = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"C:\Users\Karan\OneDrive\Desktop\2010.pdf");
    if (file != null)
    {
        isExist = true;
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    isExist = false;
}
```