# If else DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, wpf

i used DirectoryInfo to get files from a folder.

but let say the directory to the folder does not exist

i want a message that says ("directory not found")

```
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\nour\Desktop\Gedaan");
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.DOCX");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {

            LB2.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
```

Comment: You certainly have searched for existing answers before asking. What makes this question different to others where it was explained how to check whether a directory exists or not? Why `Directory.Exists` or `DirectoryInfo.Exists` don't work for you?

Comment: [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a file/directory exists: is there a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570930/check-if-a-file-directory-exists-is-there-a-better-way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Exists` method of `DirectoryInfo` class to check to check whether directory exists or not.

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\nour\Desktop\Gedaan");
if(dinfo.Exists)
{
   //your code
}
```

Comment: Depending on the situation this might violate the "Tell, don't ask" principle.

Answer (score 1):

The file-system can change under your feet, so it's generally better to make an attempt with the file-system and take appropriate corrective measures if you encounter an exception.

So instead of testing with `dinfo.Exists` then crossing your fingers that the same situation persists on the next few lines, just go ahead and try, then mop up any mess:

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\nour\Desktop\Gedaan");
FileInfo[] files;
try
{
    files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.DOCX");
}
catch(DirectoryNotFoundException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ouch");
}
```

after all, any hardened code will need to catch this exception anyway, even if you believe that some microseconds ago the directory existed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do this:

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\nour\Desktop\Gedaan");

if (!dinfo.Exists) // <---- check existence here
{
    // your message here
}
else
{
    // rest of your code here...
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.DOCX");
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        LB2.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```